# VIFGC_ovedom function in GenABEL

Tags: nlm

I am using non-additive GWAS models implemented in GenABEL. VIFGC function for dominant and recessive GWAS non-additive model is working fine but for overdominance inheritance with the same data, VIFGC_ovedom function is giving an error: 
Error: Error in nlm(GC_VIF_nlm, c(F = F1, K = K1)) : missing value in parameter

Also, how to calculate phenotypic variance explained by the significant markers in these non-additive models.

Thanks,